# Jupyter reverts signal handler to default when running next cell

Tags: python, jupyter, sigint, signal-handling

My custom defined signal handler gets reverted in jupyter when I run the very next cell. This doesn't appear to be the case when running python and ipython.

[image: Jupyter reverts sigint]

Answer (score 1):

It's dirty, but you could do something like

```py
try:
    # prevent Jupyter from reverting the signal handler before executing a cell:
    # https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/14c385318/ipykernel/kernelbase.py#L425-L432
    kernel = get_ipython().kernel  # type:ignore [name-defined]
    kernel.pre_handler_hook = lambda: None
    kernel.post_handler_hook = lambda: None
except NameError:
    # normal Python environment
    pass
```

where you set your signal handler.